# How to prove that withouting using Gelfand spectral radius theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T$ be a bounded linear operator on $X$. Assume that there is an integer $n\ge 1$ so that $\|T^n\|<1$. Show that $I-T$ is invertible and
$$
(I-T)^{-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty T^j
$$

How to prove that withouting using Gelfand spectral radius theorem?

---

I apply Neumann series property to $T^n$: let $S=I-T^n$. Since $\|I-S\|<1$, then $S$ is invertible.

Since $$S=(I-T)(I+T+T^2+\dots+T^{n-1}) $$ and $(I-T)$ commutes with $(I+T+T^2+\dots+T^{n-1}) $, then $I-T$ is invertible.

Moreover,
$$
S^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (I-S)^k
$$
that is
$$
(I-T^n)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty T^{nk}
$$

But I am stuck here...

Answer (score 1):

Show that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \|T^{j} \|<\infty$ by observing that any $m$ can be written as $kn+r$ for some non-negative integer $k$ and some $r \in\{0,1,2...,n-1\}$. This implies that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} T^{j}$ is a bounded operator.
Now it is just a simple verification that $(I-T) (\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} T^{j})=(\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} T^{j}) (I-T)=I$.

[$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \|T^{jn+r} \|\leq \|T^{r}\|\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \|T^{n} \|^{j}<\infty$. Sum this over $r$].

Comment: So $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\|T\|^r$ is bounded because $\|T\|$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  @H.YDuan